# How to publish topics at specific rate?(Python)

Tags: ros, sleep, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have 5 topics publishing images at different rates. I want them to publish at the same rate and hence I am trying to set the rostopic hz to a constant rate for all the 5 topics. How can I do it in rospy?

My understanding is that rospy.Rate() will work only for that loop of code. How can I set the rate a which the messages are being published?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255940/how-to-publish-topics-at-specific-rate?(python)/) by [Joy16](https://answers.ros.org/users/27343/joy16/) on ROS Answers with karma: 112 on 2017-03-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This needs to be done/handled in the node actually sending the messages. Either they provide a possibility to set the rate, or not. Typcially, for most sensors (cameras, laser scanners, ...), they don't. You will get your messages as fast as possible.

If you want, you could, however, push all those topics through a `topic_tools throttle`.
See the [ROS wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/topic_tools/throttle) on the syntax.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2017-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Joy16](https://answers.ros.org/users/27343/joy16/) on 2017-03-02**:
Thank you very much!